# How to get fb user photos in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to retrieve facebook user photos through GraphRequest by the following way
code:

```
enter code here  final ArrayList[] alFBAlbum = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList<>()};

/*make API call*/
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),  //your fb AccessToken
            "/" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId() + "/albums",//user id of login user
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("fb_album_response", "Facebook Albums: " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        if (response.getError() == null) {
                            JSONObject joMain = response.getJSONObject(); //convert GraphResponse response to JSONObject
                            if (joMain.has("data")) {
                                JSONArray jaData = joMain.optJSONArray("data"); //find JSONArray from JSONObject
                                alFBAlbum[0] = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < jaData.length(); i++) {//find no. of album using jaData.length()
                                    JSONObject joAlbum = jaData.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String my_id=joAlbum.optString("id");//convert perticular album into JSONObject
                                    Log.d("my_facebook_id",my_id);
                                    GetFacebookImages(my_id); //find Album ID and get All Images from album
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Test",response.getError().toString());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

    ).executeAsync();
```

by using this cod i can able to get fb user albums but it returns null array 
like this:

```
enter code here  {
  "data":[]
 }, 
   error: null
  }
```

can you tell me how to get fb user photos?

Comment: Did you ask the user for the permission necessary to view their albums …?

Comment: i dont know how to ask the user to accept the permissions especially  to access the photos

Comment: Well then start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking And what permission you need, you find under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums/

Comment: above links saying that it requires user_photos permission and publish_action permission,but it does not have info about how to give permissions  sir........

Comment: All the first link does is explain how you ask users for permissions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked to `get photos` from Facebook account.After searching many hours Facebook Developers pages,I got solution for your question, I have provided link to get Facebook user photos, follow that. 
**Link:** 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/#Reading

```
/* make the API call */
Bundle params  = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("fields","images");

new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/"+"USER ID"+"/photos",
params,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
         /* You can parse this response using Json  */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: great answer but how to get the images in order by date?? latest 50 suppose